# JavaFX. How to make the border of imageview, when I click the imageview?

Tags: javafx

In javaFX, I want make a imageview that can change border when I click.
When click once, then imageview has a border.
When click again, then imageview doesn't have a border.

How can I make that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you will need:

1. a [`PseudoClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) for toggling the CSS state
2. a wrapping [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), because the `ImageView` itself does neither support a background nor a border.

---

A simple working example (the toggling of the `PseudoClass` is done with the help of a `BooleanProperty`, which is common practice and makes the management of its state easier):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    PseudoClass imageViewBorder = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("border");

    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(
            new Image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG"));

    BorderPane imageViewWrapper = new BorderPane(imageview);
    imageViewWrapper.getStyleClass().add("image-view-wrapper");

    BooleanProperty imageViewBorderActive = new SimpleBooleanProperty() {
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            imageViewWrapper.pseudoClassStateChanged(imageViewBorder, get());
        }
    };

    imageview.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> imageViewBorderActive
            .set(!imageViewBorderActive.get()));

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(imageViewWrapper);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(15));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(
            getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

and the necessary CSS:

```
.image-view-wrapper:border {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 5;
}
```

Comment: Oh! It's very nice! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @DavidKim if that answers your question please mark this answer accordingly.